# How to create a log file based on logged in user using ASP.NET session and log4net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, log4net

I'm not sure this is a valid way of asking this question. 
I implemented logging using log4net, I was able to create a log file, and can look for the information in log file. 
So far I didn't implement the user profiles, I was asked to create log files based on the user with the format of [AID_YYYYMMDD]. Please someone suggest me the best way to learn log4net and implement the user profile based file name.

Comment: No, it's not a valid way of asking a question. There is no "?"

Comment: Each log4net appender can only write to one file at a time. If you want to have multiple open files - ie one per user - these options come to mind. 1) have one appender per user, defined programatically. This will probably not scale very well. 2) Set the file on the appender on a per-call basis, using a lock. This will have immediate performance impact and won't scale either. Your best option is to store the user info in the log, and then partition the logs per-user in post-processing.

Comment: did you tried using ***Enterprise Library*** ?

Answer (score 1):

Log4Net has **aspnet-request** to get the Current User. You will need to format the way you want it.

```
%aspnet-request{AUTH_USER}
```

[Documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.13/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.PatternLayout.html)

Comment: Thank you win, 
I want to know how can I create a file for every user based on the name and how can I say the application to look in the application, whether the file name is already existing and if it's not existing create a new one, and log the information into the associated log file based on the user.

Comment: Wow! Each user has own log file! It could be very bad design. Please do not do that.

Comment: @Win which is better design ? why bad own logfile for each user ?

Comment: Storing log in database is a best option. Mainly, you can filter them and review those logs easily.